# How to fix height in fluid layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

On RWD website design page, i have 918px of height for each boxes am using, how to set a height for the same?

If i set height to auto or 100% it doesn't work, if i fix the height to 918px, it is fine for desktop, but not for the mobile media.

```
.box{
    background-color:#0c71b8;
    height:100%;
    min-height:918px;   
    }
```

The boxes are of 960px X 918px in size, and in that box i have images and text contents with a background color for it. So how do i fix a height in percentage?

Comment: You could potentially use the `vh` unit instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1317805

Comment: can you show us more code (markup) please or make a demo (like a fiddle)?

Comment: @Dura here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59oex2ux/

Answer (score 0):

All parent elements of .box need to have a height of 100% then it should work.

Comment: your html ist not valid!

Answer (score 0):

Try below two solutions.

jQuery - Dynamically find the window height and apply same height on html element.

```
function handleResize() {
  var hgt = $(window).height();
  $('.box').css({'height':hgt+'px'}); // HTML element names
}

$(function(){
  handleResize();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    handleResize();
  });
});
```

CSS - Make absolute position and make top & bottom value zero.

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Well am using the fluid layout in dreamweaver, so i guess , the height i need control with the css itself?

Comment: It's depend on your HTML skeleton, You can choose any of above options. Most of the case jQuery option will suite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each box with a parent `div` with the desired height, like 918px and then set the box height to `100%`.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/59oex2ux/2/)

EDIT:

The previous demo is not right. You should also add `overflow:auto` to the parent div.

See the **[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59oex2ux/3/)**

Comment: Well that again works for the desktop layout, but NOT the mobile layout. The 918px should fix as a percentage to the mobile/tab layout also.

Comment: @Sharath-designer, you're right, I missed a bit. Please check the updated demo.

Comment: The overflow:auto hides the box, i cannot see it.

Comment: @Sharath-designer are you keeping the same structure as in the above new demo?

Comment: The fluid, parent and take_action is placed in one css file (fluidlayout.css).
Body is in another css file.
It is a responsive website am working in dreamweaver cc. Which has its fluidlayout.css file and a boilerplate.css file.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes the html structure is same.

Comment: Are you sure the css for `parent` and `take_action` aren't overriden? By boilerplate.css for instance?

Comment: Yes, just checked, there is nothing that is overridden by the boilerplate.css or any other css file.

Comment: Let me work around and see if i can fix it. If not, I will get back on this one. Thanks for your time Dura.